# Why does Gremlin idx returns with null although the DB is not empty?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin

I am opening a graph using:

```
g = new Neo4jGraph('...path...');
```

then adding a vertex using:

```
myVertex = g.addVertex(['type':'X', 'Y':Z]);
```

I can see the db afterwards has a single vertex (using Gephi)
but when I run:

```
if (g.idx(T.v) != null )
```

it always returns false.
Should the indexing be turned on somehow?
Does Gremlin require a specific Neo4j version?

Adding some log info:

```
...
==>v[22092]
==>v[22093]
==>v[22094]
==>v[22095]
gremlin> g.idx(T.v)
==>null
gremlin> g.idx("vertices")
==>null
gremlin> g.indices
gremlin>
```

Tried this on Gremlin 1.3 - same results. So I guess it is something I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think creating indices in Neo4j with Gremlin might be broken. Evidence includes issues raised against [neo4j](https://github.com/neo4j/community/issues/169), [blueprints](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/issues/200) and [the REST plugin](https://github.com/neo4j/gremlin-plugin/issues/4). Even if that's not the case, Gremlin doesn't really have first-class access to indices in Neo4j- eg, it can't create full-text indices last time I checked. Not sure if it can even create relationship indices in Neo.

I use a Gremlin/Groovy snippet [found in the Neo4j docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/gremlin-plugin.html#rest-api-send-an-arbitrary-groovy-script---lucene-sorting)

```
neo4j = g.getRawGraph()
idxManager = neo4j.index()
personIndex = idxManager.forNodes('vertices')
```

I realize this breaks the nice abstraction layer that is Gremlin, but afterwards you can go about your day using Gremlin methods like `g.idx('vertices')`.

EDIT:

To get to the index before an index change is "visible" to Gremlin, try this:

```
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.pgm.impls.neo4j.Neo4jIndex;
ind = new Neo4jIndex('vertices', Vertex.class, g)
```

The advantage this has over the gist I linked in the comments is that `ind` is a Gremlin index, and can half the usual Gremlin treatment applied. OTOH, the gist in the comments has full access to the raw index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it got me a step farther. The index is now created but it is only effective from the second run of the script. As if it is not 'committed' (tried using tx.success/finish). Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: I'm afraid this is part of the problem with Gremlin/Neo4j indices- at least as referenced by those issues. It looks like Gremlin binds all name/index to a hashmap, instead of looking them up every time g.idx() is called... Hm. One solution would be to just keep using the raw Neo4j index, like in this gist https://gist.github.com/1558540

Answer (score 0):

How to create Neo4j index using Gremlin in the Neo4j web console :

```
gremlin> g.createManualIndex('test2', Vertex.class)
==> MANUAL[test2:Vertex]
gremlin> test2=g.idx('test2')
==> MANUAL[test2:Vertex]
gremlin> hendy=g.v(1673)
==> v[1673]
gremlin> hendy.name
==> Hendy Irawan
gremlin> test2.put('name', 'Hendy Irawan', hendy)
==>
gremlin> test2.get('name', 'Hendy Irawan')
==> v[1673]
```

Note: `g.createAutomaticIndex()` won't do what most people would expect here, it will create a Neo4j manual index that is automatically updated by Blueprints to index ALL NODES (i.e. `Vertex` class) with a `name` property.

Taken from: https://github.com/neo4j/community/issues/397#issuecomment-5024341

Reference: https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Graph-Indices